# how to solve the problem A RenderFlex overflowed by 104 pixels on the bottom. in flutter?

Tags: flutter

i have a login page in which appears this error when i'm trying to insert text in an input : A RenderFlex overflowed by 104 pixels on the bottom.

here is a part of my code  :

```
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
           body: Center(
           child: Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.teal])),
          child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0, bottom: 0.0),
            child: Image.asset(
              'asset/img/téléchargement.jpg',
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 3, 35, 60),
            elevation: 4.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[...
```

i have to put padding inside the card but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your body with
`SingleChildScrollView()`
Your code should look like this:

```
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
           body: SingleChildScrollView(child:Center(
           child: Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.teal])),
          child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0, bottom: 0.0),
            child: Image.asset(
              'asset/img/téléchargement.jpg',
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 3, 35, 60),
            elevation: 4.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[...
```

Assuming that overflow is at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: your solution is good but i had to insert this property ` height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`, to the container and it works very well

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SingleChildScrollView()` like this:

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      child: //CONTINUE YOUR CODE FROM HERE
    ),
  ),
);
```

You can also try `physics` property inside `SingleChildScrollView()` to get better user experience

This may help you